# cordova and windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing crossplatform application with native plugins using ionic. It is important to me to have wp subproject targeted to (windows phone 8.1), no silverlight. Unfortunately

```
cordova platform add wp8
```

creates project targeted to (windows phone 8.0).

I trying to avoid changing target manually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See this article: https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/09/25/apache-cordova-gains-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-support-2-2/

You should use `cordova platform add windows` (and have a not too old Cordova version)

Answer (score 0):

First update your Cordova to latest version

```
npm update -g cordova
```

Add windows platform

```
cordova platform add windows
```

[image: CLI]

[image: Project open in Visual Studio]